# What unconfirmed transactions in Mempool get into a block?

Tags: mining-pools, block, mempool, transaction-selection

I have a question regarding picking unconfirmed transactions from the mempool. Let's say, there are 1000 transactions in the mempool. Can I randomly select some transactions, say, transaction a, b, c, d from them, and work on the nonce and create a new block? Is there any criteria about what transactions need to be in the next block?

Comment: Does https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/57823/5406 answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I added an extra question in the question you linked.